# SQL Server query to get the data from previous month if the column value is not present in next month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-query-store

I have a table that contains a number of menu items in restaurants with respect to each month.
and the table gets updated whenever there is a change in the number of items.

I want to change the table or make a new table to get the value of items for each month.

For example.
If latest month is April

| Restaurant | Number of items | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 1/1/2021 |
| A | 15 | 1/21/2021 |
| B | 12 | 1/1/2021 |
| C | 30 | 2/1/2021 |
| A | 22 | 3/31/2021 |
| B | 15 | 4/1/2021 |

I want the new table to have the above rows plus the missing months with same data as last month

| Restaurant | Number of items | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 20 | 1/1/2021 |
| A | 15 | 1/21/2021 |
| A | 15 | 2/21/2021 |
| A | 22 | 3/1/2021 |
| A | 22 | 4/1/2021 |
| B | 12 | 1/1/2021 |
| B | 12 | 2/1/2021 |
| B | 12 | 3/1/2021 |
| B | 15 | 4/1/2021 |
| C | 30 | 2/1/2021 |
| C | 30 | 3/31/2021 |
| C | 30 | 4/1/2021 |

Thanks for the help guys appreciated

Comment: What is the data type of `month`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

Assuming that `month` is stored as a date with the first first day of the  month, then a simple method uses recursive CTEs:

```
with cte as (
      select restaurant, num_items, month,
             dateadd(month, -1,
                     coalesce(lead(month) over (partition by restaurant order by month),
                              max(month) over ()
                             )
                    ) as end_month
      from t
      union all
      select restaurant, num_items, dateadd(month, 1, month), end_month
      from cte
      where month < end_month
     )
select *
from cte
order by restaurant, month;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0b29ca4a2027ca770fe790a7aadf5710) is a db<>fiddle.